# Binding Dictionary<string,List<Class>> to multiple TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

So I've got some data that I want to store in a treeview and I have it working with 2 branches but I'm stuck on getting more than that. I think a dictionary would be best for this cause it'll be easiest to store the IDs in a key when I come to add in the 'sanity checks'

How I want my data to be presented:

```
--Internet Checks
----- 'Date, message, status'
--------- 'Details'
--Server Checks
----- 'Date, message, status'
--------- 'Details'
--Sanity Checks
----- 'Date, message, status'
--------- 'Details'
--------- 'Error1'
--------- 'Error2'
--------- 'Error3'
--------- 'etc'
--etc
```

And here's how it looks at the moment

```
--Internet Checks
----- 'Date, message, status'
--Server Checks
----- 'Date, message, status'
--Sanity Checks
----- 'Date, message, status'
--etc
```

So here's how I have my xaml at the moment:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.SubItems}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Text}" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Text}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Here is my MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItem
    {
        public MenuItem()
        {
            this.SubItems = new Dictionary<int, MenuItem>();
        }

        public Dictionary<int, MenuItem> SubItems { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is how I'm currently filling in the dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<int, MenuItem> Fill(string name, Dictionary<int, MenuItem> root, List<HealthCheckHourModel> list)
        {
            root.Add(nextNum, new MenuItem { Text = name + " Checks"});
            foreach (HealthCheckHourModel hchm in list)
            {
                if (hchm.Message.Contains(name))
                {
                    root[nextNum].SubItems.Add(hchm.ID, new MenuItem { Text = hchm.StartTime + " " + hchm.Message });
                    root[nextNum].SubItems[hchm.ID].SubItems.Add(-111, new MenuItem { Text = hchm.Details });
                }
            }
            nextNum--;
            return root;
        }
```

Comment: You need a recursive algorithm to get three levels.  Current your code is only handling two levels.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- Delete ItemTemplate for HierarchicalDataTemplate.

  ```
  <TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.SubItems}">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Text}" />
              <!--<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Text}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>-->
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
  ```
- Leave ItemTemplate for HierarchicalDataTemplate, but replace DataTemplate with HierarchicalDataTemplate

  ```
  <TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.SubItems}">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Text}" />
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                  <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.SubItems}">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Text}" />
                  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
  ```